# how does this do while loop work?

Tags: c++

so I was pretty confused about loopings during class, but we have to use it in one of our homeworks. after fiddling around and tweaking a program that I compiled from the textbook, I managed to execute a do while loop the way I want it but I don't really get how this works. can someone explain this to me so that I can do it by myself from scratch? thanks

```
    do
{
    cout << "enter number of items : ";
    cin >> itemsnum;

    if (itemsnum < 1 || itemsnum > 5)
        {
        cout << "\nyou must order at least one item and not more than five items\nplease reenter the amount of items ordered : ";
        cout << endl;
        }

    else
        break;
} 
while (1);
```

so in this part of the code, users have to enter at least one number of item and not more than 5. if the data entered doesn't obey the conditions, the program will loop and prompt users to enter the amount again. I understand the "doing" part but I don't understand the "while (1)" down there. One more thing, below the "else" is a break. What does this part mean? Thank you

Comment: I fixed the typo in the question code; I don't think the question was really about that.

Answer (score 5):

It's a rather lazy way of building a loop control structure.

```
do {   } while(1);
```

is ostensibly an *infinite* loop. To exit the otherwise endless cycle, `break` is used to exit the loop.

Personally I dislike even the *appearance* of an infinite loop in a program. They do have a habit of *becoming* infinite over time due to errant refactoring. I'd prefer something like

```
   do {
       // use continue to go round again, or break to exit immediately
   } while (0); // if control reaches here, the loop finishes.
```

Comment: nice suggestion about `while(0)`, though isnt such exhaustive use of `continue` and `break` just `goto` in disguise? (not saying that `while(1)` would be better with respect to that)

Comment: @tobi303: Indeed it is, but it doesn't require a label for the `goto` target.

Comment: Other possibilities to jump to a scope end (the lambda and the exception one should be the worst): https://godbolt.org/g/fHZ8NV Other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

These three things are just different ways of writing an infinite loop:

```
do { } while (1)
while (1) { }
for (;;) { }
```

The loop is terminated by the `break` (or `return`, `abort()`, `exit()`, `std::terminate()`, `throw`, etc.) statement.

Most people would not use `do/while` for an infinite loop.  The other ways are less typing, and call out the fact that it's an infinite loop right at the top.

You can also use `true` instead of `1` in C++.  In a boolean (true/false) context, they are equivalent.

Comment: Worth mentioning that you ca  use any non-`0` value as `true`

Comment: @Fureeish: Pub quiz: what about `std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN()` as the value?

Answer (score 0):

in C and C++ 0 is considered false and any other numeric value is true, especially 1. This relates to the underlying mechanism of how comparisons are performed by the cpu.

so while(1) is the same as while(true). so your `do{X}while(1)` means do X until `1` is false or in other words do X forever.

`break` means exit this loop.